# fputs is crashing my program

Tags: c, file-handling

The following programming crashes at the first instance of 'fputs', attempting to  print 'fname' to the file Member_inf. I have also attempted printing a constant string "abcdefg" and it still failed. What exactly is being done wrong? It seems to be the initialization of the file. If possible please only help in solving the 'fputs' issue, i would rather attempt any others on my own at first as I encounter them.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>

FILE *Member_inf;
FILE *Admin_inf;
FILE *Book;

void delay(unsigned int mseconds);
struct meroDate
{
    int mm,dd,yy;
};
char *newlinestring(char t[]);
int strilen(char t[]);

int main (){

 int choice,age,contact;
 char *member_fname=(char*)malloc(30);
 char *member_lname=(char*)malloc(30);
 char *fname=(char*)malloc(20);
 char *lname=(char*)malloc(20);
 char *address=(char*)malloc(60);
 do{
 printf("\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB2\xB1\xB2\xB1");
 printf("\xB2\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1 WELCOME TO THE ST. JAGO HIGH SCHOOL LIBRARY SYSTEM ");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1");
 printf("\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\xB1\n\n");

 printf("\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDB\xB2 1:ADD MEMBER\n\n");
 printf("\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDB\xB2 2:SEARCH EXISTING MEMBER\n\n");
 printf("\xDB\xDB\xDB\xDB\xB2 3:EXIT\n\n");
 printf("\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16");
 printf("\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16");
 printf("\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16\x16");

      time_t t;
     time(&t);
      printf("Date and time:%s\n\n\n\n",ctime(&t));


 printf("Please enter your choice: ");
 scanf("%d",&choice);
 system("cls");
 printf("You chose option %d\n\n",choice);
 if (choice==3){
    printf("Thank you for visiting St. Jago High School Library. \n");
 }else if(choice==1){
    printf("***************************** MEMBER REGISTRATION ******************************\n\n");
    printf("Please enter first name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&*fname);
    printf("\nPlease enter last name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&*lname);
    printf("\nPlease enter age: \n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("\nPlease enter address: \n");
    scanf("%s",&*address);
    printf("\nPlease enter contact number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&contact);

    Member_inf=fopen("Members.txt","a");     

    fputs(fname,Member_inf);          <========    /*HERE HERE HERE*/
    fputs(lname,Member_inf);
    fputs(age,Member_inf);
    fputs(address,Member_inf);
    fputs(contact,Member_inf);

    fclose(Member_inf);
 }else if (choice==2){
    printf("***************************** MEMBER INFORMATION *******************************\n\n");
    printf("Please enter members first name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&member_fname);
    printf("\nPlease enter members last name: \n");
    scanf("%s",&member_lname);
  }else if (choice!=1,2,3){
    printf("wrong choice.Enter Again");
 }
system("cls");
}while(choice!=0);


return 0;
}

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

char* newlinestring(char t[]){
    t[strilen(t)+1]='\0';
    return t;
}

int strilen(char t[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;t[i]!=NULL;i++){}
    return i;
}
```

Comment: The first `fputs` comes immediately after `Member_inf  = fopen("Members.txt", "a");` whose success you have not checked.

Comment: Unrelated, but why not write `char member_fname[30];` instead of `char *member_fname=(char*)malloc(30);`?

Comment: I didn't make a character array because when I use fgets I will collect a character pointer and I can't compare that to an array, yes I will need to compare them.

Comment: I don't understand what that down vote is for, did I ask the question wrong? I did a bunch of research and couldnt find any similar problems at all

Comment: This community is really lacking if down votes, unnecessary ones at that are just left hanging for undetermined amounts of time. Could the person that did it either provide a suggestion or remove the down vote?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't cast the result of malloc.
2. You should always test the return value of malloc (it should not be null)
3. `scanf("%s",&*fname);` should be `scanf("%s",fname);`
   or, better yet, `fgets(fname);`
   (Obviously, this applies to all string inputs).

One word of advice - functions have return values - **utilize them**

**EDIT**
My note, `better yet`, about using `fgets()` means to stop using `scanf()` and use `fgets()` only.

Comment: `fgets(fname, ...);` after a `scanf("%d",&choice);` will be problematic as it certainly will consume the `'\n'` left over from the earlier input function and form a rump `"\n"` string.  Best to use `fgets()` for all input.

Comment: @chux - will clarify

Comment: Oh, well instead of testing for a the return value I just checked if it created the file by literally looking, seemed much easier. I'll take your advice and start using frets but referring to what I said in the question(knowing that the file was created since I saw it) I attempted to `fputs("abcdefg",Member_inf)` and this caused a crash just as well

Comment: As for testing malloc I'll take that I to co side ration as well, also I'll mention that while fputs fails to do what I want fprintf printed just fine however knowing what cause fputs to not work is a haunting matter

Comment: Consideration* I'm using a small screen, can't edit past 5 minutes. Let's just pretend we never saw that :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check if the file was opened successfully by verifying if the value of the `Member_inf` is NULL or not.
2. `fputs(age,Member_inf);` - you can not use fputs to write an integer to a file, you should cast it first to a string (maybe using itoa).
3. `for(i=0;t[i]!=NULL;i++){}` - this is not how you get the length of a string. Nobody does guarantee that the last character is a NULL. Even worse, this wont compile if you are using Microsoft's msvc compiler. You should use the builtin `strlen` function.

Comment: Hehe talk about trying to be original.

Comment: But testing for the NULL: doesn't scanf always return the last character as \n? Meaning after that any reading attempts will return a NULL?  I'm supposed to subtract one from the value before I return it originally(ignoring the \n)

Comment: Fputs, when I attempted to print age to the file was a slip up, I would have fixed it on sight if I wasn't distracted by being unable to print anything to the file (except with fprintf)

Comment: `scanf` inserts a NUL character ('\0') at the end of the string. Do not confuse the NUL ('\0') character with the NULL macro. The correct way to check we reached the end of the string is, in your case, `t[i]!='\0'`. I guess some compiler will accept if you are checking against NULL, but I would not recommend doing it.